# How to create sectioned tableview iphone sdk dynamically?

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, grouped-table

I am new to iPhone app development. I am trying to implement one application in which I want to list the items in sections. So suppose I am having three items starts with "A" , 5 items starts with "B", and so on . Item no. is not fixed for each section. How to implement this. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this apple example. Have a look at all tableview exmples.

- A Normal Tableview
- Sectioned TableView
- Indexed TableView
- TableViewCell Subviews
- Custom Cells

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318